# Python SSL Import Error in PyInstaller generated executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to distribute an executable file of a Python program I've created.
For this purpose I'm using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) .

I use Windows 7 Professional with Python 3.7
The program runs successfully when inside PyCharm and produces the expected results.

As described in the PyInstaller manuals I've created the dist folder with:

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

The log output specifies that the process finished successfully.

When trying to run the `main.exe` from the distribution folder, the below error is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_certifi.py", line 11, i
n <module>
  File "c:\users\tim\anaconda3\envs\timtf2_37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\load
er\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
[6236] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_certifi
```

Comment: can you please share your all import package names in ssl.py script

Comment: @shubham,
I do not see the `ssl.py` file in the distribution folder, there is a `_ssl.pyd` one only.

Comment: can you tell me what are the packages you imported into the main.py

Comment: I use: 
`sqlalchemy, pandas, datetime, smtplib`

Comment: use pyinstaller 3.4, i think it may help you

Comment: Tried to downgrade to pyinstaller 3.4, but it didn't help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after a couple of hours, I managed to solve the problem. 
I did several things and still unsure what was the actuall fix, but this is the step-by-step flow I've done:

1. Created a new environment using Anaconda. I've downgraded the Python version to 3.6.8, since I saw mentions of several compatibility problems with Python 3.7
2. Installed all the requirements from my project, using Anaconda, since some mention problems due to mixed usage of `pip` and `conda`.
3. Installed the latest version of `pyinstaller`.
4. Activated the new environment and run `pyinstaller` from within it on the `main.py` script of the program with `--hidden-import pyodbc` argument.

That's it, now the distibuted program works on all Windows computers in the office.

Comment: thanks， I  have the same issue with 3.7.4, sovled with 3.6.10,  and another unexpected surprise,  the size of  exe generated with 3.7.4 is 80+MB, but 30+MB  with 3.6.10