# In PyInstaller, Why Won't NumPy.Random.Common Load as a Module?

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a .py program into a Windows .exe using PyInstaller. Whenever I try to execute the .exe, the terminal opens, then closes quickly with the error:

`ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: No module named 'numpy.random.common'`

I'm not explicitly importing numpy; it's being import by pandas.

I also get this long list of warnings about modules that couldn't be loaded in the warnings log for pyinstaller.

I've tried adding `hiddenimports=['numpy.random.common']` in my .spec file, I've tried running `pyinstaller [file].py -F --hidden-import="numpy.random.common". I've read the other stackoverflow posts about pyinstaller and hiddenimports, yet nothing seems to fix this error.

I'm using a virtual environment, so I'm not sure if that's playing a part.

Here's my .spec file

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['getNewPropertiesLabels.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\[user name]\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Consulting\\[file name]'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['numpy.random.common'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Name',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True')
```

My warning file causes the post to be too long, however numpy.random.common isn't actually listed as a missing module. Neither is numpy.random.

I'm expecting this to just run properly without any issues.

Answer (score 11):

Solved this by adding three imports before `import pandas`.

```py
import numpy.random.common
import numpy.random.bounded_integers
import numpy.random.entropy
```

It seems that PyInstaller loses the path to these libraries...
Then, at the command line I wrote:

```
pyinstaller install -n APP_NAME -c --clean SCRIPT_NAME.py
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: If the above doesn't work, adding --hidden-import="numpy.random.common" --hidden-import="numpy.random.bounded_integers" --hidden-import="numpy.random.entropy" to the build may work

Answer (score 6):

I could fix it downgrading numpy from 1.17.0 to 1.16.2. In the attached image you can see the related pandas, numpy and rest of the packages I've used.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.16.2
```

[Packages used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7c6N.png)

Answer (score 1):

In my environment with `numpy==1.16.1` and `pandas==0.24.1` I do not have `numpy.random.common`

If you try to import it from python console it works?

Maybe try to upgrade/downgrade pandas (`pip install pandas==0.24.1`).

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same problem just yesterday.
At first I had a problem with `ssl` module and then with `numpy.random`, as well a list of other modules not loaded correctly...

Please look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253470/python-ssl-import-error-in-pyinstaller-generated-executable) and I've listed a number of things I've done to try and solve this problem in the following answer.

Let me know if the problem is solved by this measures, cause I wasn't able to pinpoint the exact step that solved it. (I believe it is a combination of all).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem which I'm trying to solve for hours!
[this trick](https://medium.com/@nbenton90/python-pandas-pyinstaller-watch-out-5d9af2cea867) didn't work for me although I recommend trying it, downgrading numpy and pandas solved the "import numpy problem" caused by pandas disappear.. only because now it can't find pandas! (although I specified pandas under hiddenimports)

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'numpy.random.common', 'numpy.random.bounded_integers' and 'numpy.random.entropy' to my hidden imports worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

the problem that i got was numpy was not installed

after installing numpy it worked

```
pip install numpy
```