# exe file fails to run when pandas is imported

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, exe

exe file starts but crashes with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random.common'`

I use `pyinstaller --onefile hello.py --hidden-import pandas` and 
.exe file fails.
I've tried to change the spec file with adding path to `pandas`
, but the .exe file still fails.

Contents of **hello.py** file:

```
import os
input("before loading pandas")
import pandas
print ("hello")
input('waiting for keyboard input')
```

Contents of spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

def get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path=pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_path


a = Analysis(['CreateExcelSAList.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\OneDrive - Ardovlam NV\\15. Python\\hello'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
dict_tree=Tree(get_pandas_path(),prefix='pandas',excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas+=dict_tree
a.binaries=filter(lambda x:'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='hello',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
scoll=COLLECT(exe,
            a.binaries,
            a.zipfiles,
            a.datas,
            strip=None,
            upx=True,
            name='hello')
```

Comment: What are the exact versions of `python`, `pandas`, `numpy` and `pyinstaller` that you are using?

Comment: python: 3.7-32bit; pandas: 0.25.0; pyinstaller: 3.5;numpy: 1.17.0

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a known error. Please check: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14163. There is a reference to a solution in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

i've got the solution, found here
[In PyInstaller, Why Won't NumPy.Random.Common Load as a Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264427/in-pyinstaller-why-wont-numpy-random-common-load-as-a-module)

i've imported things below just before importing pandas in my hello.py

```
import numpy.random.common
import numpy.random.bounded_integers
import numpy.random.entropy
```

After running pyinstaller hello.py, my exe file was running as expected

in another program it was not enough to import the numpy libs, i've got to change also  xx.spec file with 'hiddenimports'

```
hiddenimports=['numpy.random.common','numpy.random.entropy','numpy.random.bounded_integers'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
```