# Trying to convert a .py file to an .exe one but the process runs with many errors and .exe fails when completed

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.7

## Here is the run from windows cmd, I'm using the command

pyinstaller pythonfile.py

```
C:\Users\fpt84\Downloads\Case>pyinstaller Reserve_estimation.py
1922 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
1922 INFO: Python: 3.7.5
1922 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
1922 INFO: wrote C:\Users\fpt84\Downloads\Case\Reserve_estimation.spec
1922 INFO: UPX is not available.
1938 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\fpt84\\Downloads\\Case', 'C:\\Users\\fpt84\\Downloads\\Case']
1938 INFO: checking Analysis
1938 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1938 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1938 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
2060 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
15631 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
15662 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe
16855 INFO: Caching module hooks...
16873 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\fpt84\Downloads\Case\Reserve_estimation.py
18930 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
23013 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
23028 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
27858 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
44127 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
90015 INFO: Loading module hooks...
90015 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
90031 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
90263 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
90331 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.backends.py"...
93743 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    The GTK3 backends require PyGObject
94880 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    The GTK3 backends require PyGObject
95961 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py)
96785 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": ignored
    No module named 'IPython'
97650 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": ignored
    Failed to import any qt binding
98536 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": ignored
    Failed to import any qt binding
167586 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": ignored
    Failed to import any qt binding
168446 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    Failed to import any qt binding
170140 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
171297 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": added
173180 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
174578 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
175414 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
176309 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
177333 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
178893 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": added
180276 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
181562 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
182493 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
183380 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
184500 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
186040 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.py"...
186772 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
187104 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
187104 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pandas.py"...
195599 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-patsy.py"...
195615 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
196332 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
196493 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
197019 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
197019 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...
197173 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.linalg.py"...
197173 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.py"...
197188 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py"...
197220 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py"...
197235 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py"...
197235 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
198538 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
198845 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
198876 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
198876 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
198876 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
199320 INFO: checking Tree
199321 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
199321 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
199542 INFO: checking Tree
199542 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
199543 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
199887 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
200066 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
200110 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
200300 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
200391 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
200512 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
200543 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
200614 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
201371 WARNING: lib not found: libdcosqb.BSF6YTIPIV6BF3DZBNWD4YMH3UDU6DI7.gfortran-win32.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\convolve.cp37-win32.pyd
201448 WARNING: lib not found: libdcosqb.3VZOXZKO53O75NWVYHOUJGPASB2ZKGJ5.gfortran-win32.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\_fftpack.cp37-win32.pyd
201697 WARNING: lib not found: libopenblas.FN5FF57TWHUYLRG54LA6B33EZPHYZZL4.gfortran-win32.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_fblas.cp37-win32.pyd
201735 WARNING: lib not found: libwrap_dum.O73B2JX3DJYML5H4BWW5Q3A3HBJAOPZ6.gfortran-win32.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_fblas.cp37-win32.pyd
201813 WARNING: lib not found: libopenblas.FN5FF57TWHUYLRG54LA6B33EZPHYZZL4.gfortran-win32.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_flapack.cp37-win32.pyd
201851 WARNING: lib not found: libwrap_dum.IRYJBAZYKKFICXK5GWMZM56G37UL5UQD.gfortran-win32.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_flapack.cp37-win32.pyd
201919 WARNING: lib not found: libdet.5CWEKK7ZP27J2ASOWSCQ2Q7EMBKUXI6K.gfortran-win32.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_flinalg.cp37-win32.pyd
.
.
.
.

255561 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
255576 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
255777 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
255793 INFO: Bootloader c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
255793 INFO: checking EXE
255793 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
255793 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
255824 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\fpt84\Downloads\Case\build\Reserve_estimation\Reserve_estimation.exe
256031 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
256046 INFO: checking COLLECT
256046 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
256046 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
350779 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

I have tried installing some of the missing modules manually but it seems to be an endless process, as shown from the run log, the process ends successfully.
When I run the executable file from the dist folder it opens a cmd windows, shows a few lines of initialization but suddenly outputs some failure lines which I don't even have the time to read before the cmd windows closes back.

## How can I resolve this?, I've also tried 'pyinstaller --onefile pythonfile.py'

Comment: Are you running the exe from the build folder? Or the dist folder. The former doesn't run, and the latter does. Send me your code at legorooj@pm.me and I'll try compilation.

Comment: @Legorooj I'm running it from the dist folder

Comment: When I'm debugging `pyinstaller` exe issues, I'll use `try/except` around the call to the "main" function to catch and print the exception, and then put an `input()` statement at the bottom so that the window doesn't automatically close. It gives me enough time to read the error message and try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Pozeidon ok I've got the mail, I'll compile when on PC. What system do you run? Windows, anaconda, cpython, etc.

Comment: @Legorooj Windows 10, python 3.7.5 with pycharm

Comment: @Pozeidon same as me! Well 3.7.3 in my case

Comment: thanks for the tip @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica

Comment: @Pozeidon On line 224 - should `n_samples` be greater than (>1000) or less than (<1000)? The input prompt and the `if` statement clash.

Comment: @Pozeidon Could you go into command prompt, navigate to the directory in which the `exe` file is in, and run it like `Reserve_estimation.exe`? Then you'll be able to see the stack trace, and post it in an edit. I'd like to check that we're getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Found your error (I think).

The stack trace from the failed execution was

> ImportError: no module named 'numpy.random.common'`. Googling this, it would appear that this is a common problem, and a fix was determined in [In PyInstaller, Why Won't NumPy.Random.Common Load as a Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264427/in-pyinstaller-why-wont-numpy-random-common-load-as-a-module).

The fix was to add three lines to the start of failing script before compilation.

```py
import numpy.random.common
import numpy.random.bounded_integers
import numpy.random.entropy
```

Doing this, I compiled the executable, and *Voila!*

It ran. I did however, get a warning about some matplotlib deprecated soon to me removed function though, which didn't come up in the console run of the source that I saw, so you might want to fix that.

Also, I replaced the `time.sleep(1000)` call at the end of your code with `input('Press enter to exit...')`.