# pyInstaller AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '_NoValue'

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller

i recently made a pyqt5 app for a college project after i finished i tested it and everything worked fine thats until i converted the .py to a .exe using auto-py-to-exe(pyinstaller) i am now getting this error no matter what i do [Failed to execute script "name" due to unhandled exception :module 'numpy' has no attribute '_NoValue'] i searched online and imported numpy to test and there is in fact no such thing as numpy._NoValue, now i am stuck on what to do

this is the popup i get when running the exe

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding an explicit `import numpy as np` in script. (Found by chance)

I am using pyinstaller==5.1, python3.9

I guess pyinstaller does not handle numpy import through other package (in my case numpy was imported by matplotlib)

same type problem can be found here
[In PyInstaller, Why Won't NumPy.Random.Common Load as a Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264427/in-pyinstaller-why-wont-numpy-random-common-load-as-a-module)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error and I managed to fix it by changing the python version.

I was at the version 3.9.x and when I changed to the version 3.7.9 it worked.